# grid view to show checked checkbox and change background colour for unique rows only

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

How do I: 
add  a data row with a background colour of blue and 'check' check box
but leave the rest with a background colour of blue

see my code below. Thanks for the help

```
Dim table2 As New DataTable
' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
table2.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(Integer))
table2.Columns.Add("Drug", GetType(String))
table2.Columns.Add("Patient", GetType(String))
table2.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
' Add five rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
table2.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(10, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(125, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(150, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now)
table2.Rows.Add(2, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now)

'GridView1.DataSource = table2



For Each dr As DataRow In table2.Rows

    If dr("ID") = 21 Or dr("ID") = 150 Then

        ' add  a data row with a back ground colour - blue and check check box

    Else

        ' add  a data row with a back ground colour - yellow

    End If




Next

GridView1.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would bind the DataTable to the GridView and handle via the [RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.80%29).

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound

    'Assuming your ID column is in the first cell.
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow AndAlso _
       (e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "21" OrElse e.Row.Cells(0).Text = "150") Then

        e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue

        'Assuming CheckBox is in the second cell with ID of "IdOfCheckBox"
        CType(e.Row.Cells(1).FindControl("IdOfCheckBox"), CheckBox).Checked = True

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. What happens if my datatable has the id at cell 0 but my grid view is not set up to show the id? will this still work?

Comment: For that set 'ID' as DataKey for Gridview by adding following mark up DataKeyNames = "ID". and in code behind to retrieve the ID value ..Dim ID As Integer... ID = Convert.ToInt32(Gridview1.DataKeys(e.row).Value)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub GridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, _
  ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs)

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
                If (Check your condition ) Then
                e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Blue
                'Then find your checkbox control from row and set it's value to Checked...

   ELSE
     e.Row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.yellow

 End If
    End If
End Sub
```